# Sign MSIX from Visual Studio 2022 with certificate from Azure Key Vault

Tags: visual-studio, code-signing, azure-keyvault, msix

like the title states I want to sign a MSXI package from within VS. I have a C# application and a corresponding Windows Packaging Project. I have the Key Vault setup with the permissions a stated in the docs (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/sign-with-akv-cert).
As I understand it, I'll go to Publish > Create App Package... on the Windows Packaging Project, allow sideloading and when it comes to signing, I'll select Certs from Azure Key Vault. I enter the vault's URL, click on View Metadata and get the list of certs from the vault. However when I select it and click OK, it will say:

"There was an error importing the selected certificate to the user's local certificate store."

Sadly I cannot find anything on that error. To me it sounds like a local permission problem, but I have administrative rights on my computer and even tried to run VS as administrator, but that didn't change a thing.

Anybody has an idea?
BR,
Daniel

Answer (score 1):

I think you might need to register Visual Studio as an app with permissions to your Azure Key Vault. See the article linked below (*somewhere in the middle of the article we explain this registration process*).

When we built the [integration for Azure Key Vault in Advanced Installer](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-azure-key-vault-signing.html) we had to specifically educate our users to register our application (Advanced Installer) in their Azure tenant, otherwise, the APIs would fail.

I remember Microsoft said this is a requirement for all non-Microsoft apps, so theoretically VS should work without you having to register it inside your tenant, but it is worth a shot trying. Their docs are pretty slim in this area so I would not be surprised if this would be the solution.